# clarification for the tangential and normal components of acceleration

Tags: vectors, education, classical-mechanics, computational-mathematics, nonlinear-dynamics

please help me understand this bit from  the book:
"Vector Mechanics for Engineers Statics and Dynamics by Beer, Johnston(12th edition)"(page 692).

[image]

why or how is ${\it \Delta}e_t = 2\sin(delta\theta/2)$ ?

Comment: Just draw in the angle bisector and note the rectangular triangles that it generates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I think delta theta as a magnitude can be derived this way.